# How filter value of maven profile in log4j2.xml with SpringBoot

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I needed add a environment variable in my log4j2.xml via maven, but in spring boot project. I had a certain difficult, but i did it. =)

How code was like before.

log4j2.xml

```
<PatternLayout>
     <Pattern>${ambiente} - %d [%-6p] %c - %M - %m%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <ambiente>desenvolvimento</ambiente>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>hom</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>hom</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <ambiente>homologacao</ambiente>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>prod</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <ambiente>producao</ambiente>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the run command: `clean install -Denv=dev`

Doesn't worked =(

```
<PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>${ambiente} - %d [%-6p] %c - %M - %m%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

After trying various options, i did it.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And that, changing ${ambiente} to @ambiente@

```
<PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>@ambiente@ - %d [%-6p] %c - %M - %m%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

Running again with the same command `clean install -Denv=dev`

And now my log4j2.xml looks great =).

```
<PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>desenvolvimento - %d [%-6p] %c - %M - %m%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

And my log file

```
desenvolvimento - 2018-03-20 17:08:37,678 [ERROR ]
```

Hope it help!